# Rebuild_index does not update new items Haystack Elasticsearch Django

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

Have been looking around for this solution but can't find anything. I have just started using Haystack == 2.6.1 and am using Elasticsearch==2.4.1 and Elasticsearch server 2.4.6. I was able to perform searches and get results after following haystack's [getting started](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html). After I run

```
python manage.py rebuild_index
```

It worked the first time because like I said I was able to perform searches. But then I added 3 entries to my db and tried to rebuild and/or update the index. But now I see this:

```
RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Order.dateEntered received a naive datetime (2017-11-11 16:07:54.324473) while time zone support is active.
  RuntimeWarning)
Indexing 32 orders
GET /haystack/_mapping [status:404 request:0.004s]
```

And so when I search I still do not see my new entries. I now have 35 orders (it indexed only 32) and I'm seeing this 404 response for GET /haystack/_mapping. 
Sorry I am new so some of the questions may seem silly:

1. What is haystack expecting to GET; I have a local server running for elasticsearch but is there supposed to be a haystack server as well?
2. Would haystack fail to index new items due to the naive datetime WARNING?
3. And do I have to restart the elasticsearch server each time I add new items to the database?

UPDATE: In the morning I restarted the elasticsearch server and reran `python manage.py rebuild_index` and then it captured all 35 in the indexing process! BUT I tried adding an entry again and rerunning it and it still only indexes the 35 items - now I have 36 so it *should* be indexing 36 items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that :

```
RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Order.dateEntered received a naive datetime (2017-11-11 16:07:54.324473) while time zone support is active.
  RuntimeWarning)
```

was the issue. In `search_index.py` it updates based on the `index_queryset` function. From the 'Getting Started' documentation `index_queryset` should look like this:

```
def index_queryset(self, using=None):
    """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
    return self.get_model().objects.filter(pub_date__lte=datetime.datetime.now())
```

But since pub_date was either not the right timezone or because it was a naive format `rebuild_index` was not pulling the most up-to-date items. So I used the django.utils timezone date:

```
from django.utils import timezone

def index_queryset(self, using=None):
    """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
    return self.get_model().objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now())
```